# Keeping true color of 3d objects in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

For 2d game I need 3d objects with default colors. For example, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Po3A.png) cube, all of whose faces are painted in different colors, but it looks dark without a light, and with a light brightness of the faces is changing. How can I keep the true color of the cube?

Comment: Have you tried by applying a Material with a `Sprite > Diffuse` shader? The result should be way better.

Comment: @Andrea that's not what I need

Comment: The question is a little unclear. Do you have a visual or what behaviour you'd like? The cube image you've show us is not coloured differently on each face.

Answer (score 4):

I might not understand well your question, but you can use **Unlit/Color** shader.

This shader doesn't compute lighting, so it keeps color no matter the light conditions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using Unlit colors can be good choice, however keep in mind that there's also ambient light property in the Lightening window.
So you can keep default material, get rid of all light objects in the scene, and adjust ambient value to get the effect you want.